# Mapped drive monitoring using PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a PowerShell 2.0 script to monitor and reconnect network drives that should be mapped. It works...mostly. Once a drive is determined to be disconnected my logon script (ptt.vbs) is run and the drives are remapped. However, after that it continues to see that particular drive letter as disconnected even though it got remapped.

```
while($true) {
  $disconnectedDrives = @()
  $mappedDrives = 'J:', 'R:', 'S:', 'W:'
  foreach ($drive in $mappedDrives) {
    if (-Not (Test-Path $drive)) {
      $disconnectedDrives += $drive
    }
  }
  if ($disconnectedDrives) {
    Write-Host "$disconnectedDrives not mapped."
    Write-Eventlog -LogName 'Windows PowerShell' -Category 3 -source PowerShell -eventID 601 -EntryType Error -message "$disconnectedDrives OFFLINE and not available."
    \\dc1\NETLOGON\ptt.vbs
  }
  Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To me the mix of VBS and Powershell is suspicious.

But at least a would take a differnt way.  First create a central file whch includes the network drive configuration.  For example "\dc1\NETLOGON\ptt.csv" can look like this ...

```
J;\\srv1\shareA
R;\\srv1\shareB
S;\\srv2\shareA
W;\\srv2\shareB
```

This is the script ...

```
$Local:LogicalDiskStatus  = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Management.ManagementObject]'

$Local:NetDrvConf_Path    = "\\dc1\NETLOGON\ptt.csv"
$Local:NetDrvConf_List    = @()
$Local:NetDrvConf_DrvType = [UInt32]4

$Local:WshNetworkObj      = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network

while($true) {
    # adding the logical disk status to a list indexed by DeviceID 
    $LogicalDiskStatus.Clear()
    Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_LogicalDisk" | ForEach-Object { $LogicalDiskStatus.Add((($_.DeviceID) -replace ":"), $_) }

    if (!($NetDrvConf_List.Count)) {
        Try {
            $NetDrvConf_List.Clear()
            $NetDrvConf_List = Import-Csv -Path $NetDrvConf_Path -Delimiter ";"         
        }
        Catch [System.Exception] {
            $Local:ErrorMsg = ("Cannot load network drive configuration file `"{0}`".  Error message: {1}" -f $NetDrvConf_Path, ($_.Exception.Message))
            Write-Host $ErrorMsg -ForegroundColor red
            Write-Eventlog -LogName "Windows PowerShell" -Category 3 -Source PowerShell -EventId 601 -EntryType Error -Message $ErrorMsg
        }
    }

    $NetDrvConf_List | ForEach-Object {
        $Local:Current_DriveLetter = ($_.Drive).ToUpper()
        $Local:Current_DriveID     = ("{0}:" -f $Current_DriveLetter)
        $Local:Current_UNCPath     = $_.UNCPath

        Write-Host ("Check configuration:  {0}  {1}" -f $Current_DriveID, $Current_UNCPath)

        # drive in use?
        if ( ($LogicalDiskStatus.ContainsKey($Current_DriveLetter)) ) {
            # drive is a network drive?
            if (!(($LogicalDiskStatus.$Current_DriveLetter.DriveType).Equals($NetDrvConf_DrvType))) {
                $Local:ErrorMsg = ("Drive `"{0}`" is already in use, but not as a network drive!  The current drive type is `"{1}`" not `"4`"." -f $Current_DriveID, ($LogicalDiskStatus.$Current_DriveLetter.DriveType) )
                Write-Host $ErrorMsg -ForegroundColor red
                Write-Eventlog -LogName "Windows PowerShell" -Category 3 -Source PowerShell -EventId 602 -EntryType Error -Message $ErrorMsg
            # drive is NOT to the expected UNC path?
            } elseif (!(($LogicalDiskStatus.$Current_DriveLetter.ProviderName).Equals($Current_UNCPath))) {
                Try {
                    Write-Host ("Network drive `"{0}`" unexpectedly connected to `"{1}`".  Trying to disconnect." -f $Current_DriveID, ($LogicalDiskStatus.$Current_DriveLetter.ProviderName)) -ForegroundColor yellow
                    $WshNetworkObj.RemoveNetworkDrive($Current_DriveID, $true, $true)
                    Write-Host ("=> successfully disconnected.") -ForegroundColor green
                }
                Catch [System.Exception] {
                    $Local:ErrorMsg = ("Error disconnecting `"{0}`".  Connected to `"{1}`".  Error message: {2}" -f $Current_DriveID, $Current_UNCPath, ($_.Exception.InnerException) )
                    Write-Host $ErrorMsg -ForegroundColor red
                    Write-Eventlog -LogName "Windows PowerShell" -Category 3 -Source PowerShell -EventId 603 -EntryType Error -Message $ErrorMsg
                }
            } else {
                Write-Host "=> correct connected" -ForegroundColor green
            }
        }

        # drive is unused?
        if (!(((Get-PSProvider -PSProvider FileSystem).Drives.Name).Contains($Current_DriveLetter))) {
            Try {
                Write-Host ("Connecting network drive `"{0}`" to `"{1}`"." -f $Current_DriveID, $Current_UNCPath) -ForegroundColor yellow
                $WshNetworkObj.MapNetworkDrive($Current_DriveID, $Current_UNCPath, $true)
                Write-Host ("=> successfully connected.") -ForegroundColor green
            }
            Catch [System.Exception] {
                $Local:ErrorMsg = ("Error connecting `"{0}`" to `"{1}`". Error message: {2}" -f $Current_UNCPath, $Current_DriveID, ($_.Exception.InnerException) )
                Write-Host $ErrorMsg -ForegroundColor red
                Write-Eventlog -LogName "Windows PowerShell" -Category 3 -Source PowerShell -EventId 604 -EntryType Error -Message $ErrorMsg
            }
        }
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```